# How to think about O(nlogn) solution in the first shot?

Tags: java, data-structures, big-o

I always come up with a solution which is `O(n^2)` (brute force) but I never get to `O(nlogn)` or `O(n)` in the first few mins or after some time when I read through the problem (thought process I meant). For larger data sets the `O(n^2)` always fails. How to approach in thinking of a problem to gain optimal solution. Could you share some thoughts about this. Here is one problem I am working on which gets timed out for larger data sets (full description [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/pairs/problem)).

[image]

**Code :-**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    static int pairs(int[] a,int k) {

        if( a.length==0 || a==null )
        return 0;

        int counter=0;        

        for( int i=0;i<a.length;i++ ){
            for( int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++) {
                if( Math.abs(a[i]-a[j])==k )
                    counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int res;

        String n = in.nextLine();
        String[] n_split = n.split(" ");

        int _a_size = Integer.parseInt(n_split[0]);
        int _k = Integer.parseInt(n_split[1]);

        int[] _a = new int[_a_size];
        int _a_item;
        String next = in.nextLine();
        String[] next_split = next.split(" ");

        for(int _a_i = 0; _a_i < _a_size; _a_i++) {
            _a_item = Integer.parseInt(next_split[_a_i]);
            _a[_a_i] = _a_item;
        }

        res = pairs(_a,_k);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's such a vague question. Every problem is different, and even though there are techniques that are useful to know to solve certain class of problems optimally, there's no miracle. Optimizing an algorithm can be hard, unless you're a genius you will always need to think more than a few minutes to find a clever answer to a problem

Comment: Also, if you want help with your specific problem, I recommend you posting a link to its description. That would be a better, more focused question that people can actually answer

Comment: Could you help me with this problem(code) I have posted...

Comment: Yes, if you post the problem description.

Comment: Just added the sample data and problem explanation for the code thats posted

Comment: Sort the array. Then just sweep through the array linearly.

Comment: @Teja I answered this in my post

Comment: @Teja you should have added the actual link to the question, I just found it, and it specifies that the values inside the array are unique, which changes the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I do is sit down and look for how you would solve the problem as a human. Look for shortcuts, or patterns.

In this problem you are looking for two numbers that are k apart. Iterate through the numbers. As you go, add them to a set. Then if that number plus or minus k is in the set, increase your counter.

Pseudocode:

```
Set<Integer> set;
for(int i:a){
  set.add(i);
  if(set.contains(i-k)
    counter++;
  if(set.contains(i+k)
    counter++;
}
Return counter;
```

O(n) solution

Comment: Given that the values in the array are unique, your approach will work if you fix a little bug: if both `i - k` and `i + k` are present in the set you should count two pairs instead of a single one

Answer (score 1):

A small Scala solution since vikarjramun is not fixing the bug in his answer:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable._

object Solution {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val lines = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines()
        val k     = lines.next().split(' ')(1).toInt
        val arr   = lines.next().split(' ').map(_.toInt)

        val set = HashSet[Int]()
        var count = 0

        for (i <- arr) {
            set.add(i);
            if (set.contains(i - k)) count += 1
            if (set.contains(i + k)) count += 1
        }

        println(count)
    }
}
```

Since `HashSet` has a constant complexity for lookups and insertions, the whole algorithm is `O(n)`.

Comment: sorry, didn't see your message until now

Comment: That's ok. I actually missed the fact that you are also returning the double of the sum at the end instead of the sum itelf. I'm pretty confident the code above works because it passed HackerRank's tests. I upvoted your answer anyway since you were the first one to propose a linear solution

Comment: I actually didn't read the problem statement, and I also misread Teja's code, so your solution is right.